# Point forecast and setting dates properly

Tags: r, lubridate, forecast

I have daily data from sales for each days in the period from 2019-01-01 until 2019-12-01. You can see data with code below.

```
#Input data
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

    DATA_TEST<-data.frame(date_of_sale = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-01"), by = "day"),
                          value=sample(1:100, 335, replace=TRUE))
```

So my intention is to make properly time series object in order to making forecast with that data.So for that reason I try with this line of code.I try to set frequency to 365.25 and this how my ts object look like.

```
   MY_DATA<- ts(DATA_TEST[,2],frequency = 365.25, start = decimal_date(as.Date("2019-01-01")))
```

[image]

On above graph you can see that series begin from 2019.So next steep should be forecast 14 period ahead with this time series but I think my forecast is not going well because I didn't have dates like output.

```
model <- tbats(MY_DATA)
forecast<-predict(model,h=14)
plot(forecast, main = "TBATS Forecast", include=14)
```

[image]

[image]

So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem and get point forecast but with dates not with figures like highlighted figures with yellow color.I don't know maybe I made something wrong with frequency but I am not sure.

Comment: Can you use the fable package, it really helps tidying things up

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have TBATS yet

Comment: how have you defined your `tbats` object from this line `forecast<-predict(tbats,h=14)`?

Comment: I add one more line model<- tbats(MY_DATA). So please check again if you can.